# How to get vuejs url access with subfolder not subdomain?

Tags: vue.js, dns, subdomain, hosting, subdirectory

im confused in my companion hosting server using ip address and subfolder for access web portal and etc. then im using vuejs but im just know push to hosting with subdomain. and my question how to configure vuejs to use subfolder access on my hosting?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the path to your subfolder in the `publicPath` variable from your `vue.config.js`.

If you don't have a `vue.config.js` file in your project, create one.

Here is an example:

```js
// vue.config.js

module.exports = {
  publicPath: "/subfolder/"
}
```

So if your application will be hosted at `https://your-domain.com/subfolder/` , then you set `publicPath` equal to `/subfolder/`

Read more about `publicPath` in Vue's documentation: https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath